# Solve for how many values of $x$, $f(x)=$ $\frac{1000^x}{x!}$ attains the maximum?

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima

Solve for how many values of $x$, $f(x)=$ $\frac{1000^x}{x!}$ attains the maximum?

I was solving this past problem of an UG entrance. So I found that its go'in to be maximum at $1$ value of n because at one point only its go'in to be undefined.So the maxima exists only at that one value of $x$.But the ans turned out to be $2$ values for $x$.I didn't get it why??

Comment: I assume $x$ is supposed to be a positive integer here? And what do you mean by "undefined"? - A function cannot have a maximum a a point if it is undefined here.

Comment: **_Mark Bennet is correct_**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $$T_x=\frac{1000^x}{x!}$$
now observe that $$T_{n+1}=\frac{1000}{n+1} \cdot T_n$$
We can notice that the expression  is increasing for $0<n \leq 998$ since we  have $$\frac{1000}{n+1} \geq 1$$At $n=999$ the multiplier becomes 1 thus $$f(999)=f(1000)$$
Thus there are two points of maxima .....
you can continue this argument for  continuous $f(x)$ instead of the discrete $T_n$ I defined...

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Just a quick question. Could you explain a little as to why $f(1000)$ is also a maximum? Can't figure it out.